# Anomalize package detecting anomalies in a flat time-series

Tags: r, time-series, anomaly-detection

I am using Anomalize package for doing anomaly detection on several time-series. While going through the results of some of them I found that even those series which are flat and have same values across all periods, anomalies are being detected in some observations. Here is the code

```
library(anomalize)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)
x<-rep(-1,60)
x<-as.data.frame(x)
Month_Year<-c("Apr_14","May_14","Jun_14","Jul_14","Aug_14","Sep_14","Oct_14","Nov_14","Dec_14","Jan_15"
,"Feb_15","Mar_15","Apr_15","May_15","Jun_15","Jul_15","Aug_15","Sep_15","Oct_15","Nov_15"
,"Dec_15","Jan_16","Feb_16","Mar_16","Apr_16","May_16","Jun_16","Jul_16","Aug_16","Sep_16"
,"Oct_16","Nov_16","Dec_16","Jan_17","Feb_17","Mar_17","Apr_17","May_17","Jun_17","Jul_17"
,"Aug_17","Sep_17","Oct_17","Nov_17","Dec_17","Jan_18","Feb_18","Mar_18","Apr_18","May_18"
,"Jun_18","Jul_18","Aug_18","Sep_18","Oct_18","Nov_18","Dec_18","Jan_19","Feb_19","Mar_19")

x$time<-as.Date(paste("01",Month_Year,sep = "_"),format ="%d_%b_%y")
colnames(x)<-c("TB","time")
x<-select(x,time,TB)
# x<-tbl_df(x)
x<-as_tbl_time(x,index = time)
x%>% glimpse()
x_anomalized<-x %>% time_decompose(TB,method='stl',merge = TRUE) %>% anomalize(remainder,method='iqr', alpha = 0.05)%>%time_recompose()

p1 <- x_anomalized %>%
  plot_anomaly_decomposition() +
  ggtitle("Freq/Trend = 'auto'")

p1
```

[image]

I think the problem is happening because of the seasonal decomposition. But then I thought the time_decompose() was detecting seasonality and then deciding on the seasonality value.

Comment: Indeed, I think the problem lies in the decomposition. The trend is recovered fine, but it also detects a seasonality and remainder. I guess it happens because the algorithm runs into some issues with your time-series being zero-variance. It is very hacky, and be careful with actual small values, but setting these small values to 0 fixes your example: `x_anomalized  <- x %>% time_decompose(TB,method='stl',merge = TRUE, frequency = "auto", message = F) %>% mutate_at(vars(observed:remainder), ~ if_else(. < 1e-14, 0, .)) %>%  anomalize(remainder,method='iqr', alpha = 0.05) %>% time_recompose()`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what i have done. I rounded off the small errors to zero and those values are not showing up as anomalies anymore, but I was hoping the package was taking care of it.